# Pager does not show items, Magento2

Tags: php, magento, pagination, magento2, pager

Pager doesn't show items. It does show count of them and even paginates. But it paginates nothing.

The code is below.

> Block/TestClass.php

```
<?php
namespace Wade\Crud\Block;
class TestClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
/**public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}*/
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_postFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Wade\Crud\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
        )       {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout(){
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getModelData()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager')
                ->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5))->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection($this->getModelData());
                $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
                $this->getModelData()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml(){
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
    public function getModelData(){
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $data = $this->_postFactory->create();
        $collection = $data->getCollection();       
            return $collection;
    }

}
?>
```

And the .phtml template file

```
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

The ouput shows:
Items 1 to 5 of 14 total. So at least correct number of items in collection is shown. But again, no items is shown.

Comment: you are echoing the paging links, not the items. Echo the items too

Comment: How to achieve that? echo print_r($collection->getData()) just shows all of the items on all of the pages. I just can't figure out how to link pages and collections, it seems like.

Comment: Got it. Should've just define PageSize and CurPage via setPageSize() and setCurPage() methods.

Comment: great stuff, good luck!

Comment: Can you help me on the ajax pagination issue in magento 2.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316910/magento-2-custom-added-ajax-pagination-not-working